# Imaco - Extracting HREF from Linkedin Search Results

Tags: href, extract, linkedin-api, imacros, data-extraction

I am trying to extract profile URLs from linkedin search results pages but i am not getting any appropriate results, can you please help me out with below code.

'll look forward to hearing from you further, Thanks in advance!

Regards// Rebecca

```
VERSION BUILD=8850919 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?type=all&keywords=&orig=GLHD&rsid=&pageKey=member-home&trkInfo=&search=Search
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=2 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=3 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=4 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=5 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=6 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=7 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=8 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=9 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=10 TYPE=H3 ATTR=* EXTRACT=HREF
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=results.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code strings of "TAG POS=... EXTRACT=HREF" with:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:profile-photo EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:profile-photo EXTRACT=HREF
```

etc.